# cannot convert viewModel and ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, json, mvvm, converters, observablecollection

In my follow second line, I found a convert error argument:

```
UserStackVM _listeStack = JsonWorker.ReadData();
ListeStacks = new ObservableCollection<UserStackVM>(_listeStack); // here
```

My error is:

> cannot convert from 'MyStack.ViewModels.UserStackVM' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

UserStackVM is a ViewModel:

```
#region Properties
        private string name;
        ...
        private string[] path;
        ...
        #endregion
```

JsonWorker is a static class using Json.NET (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
#region Properties
        private static string _json;
        private static UserStackVM _userStack;
        #endregion     

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Open the json config file. Create it if he doesn't exist.
        /// </summary>
        private static void OpenFile()
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(@"config.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    _json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Read the json config file and return all data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static UserStackVM ReadData()
        {
            OpenFile();
            _userStack = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserStackVM>(_json);
            return _userStack;
        }    
        #endregion
```

Per advance, thanks for your help.

Comment: `ReadData` is only returning a single value where as the constructor for `ObservableCollection` requires an `IEnumerable<T>`. Simply change to using the collection initialiser `ListeStacks = new ObservableCollection<UserStackVM> { _listeStack };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'MyStack.ViewModels.**UserStackVM**' to **'System.Collections.Generic.List'**

That [ObservableCollection(T) Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) expects a `List<T>` (list of instances); you are only providing a single instance. Change it to

```
UserStackVM _listeStack = JsonWorker.ReadData();
ListeStacks = new ObservableCollection<UserStackVM>(); 

ListeStacks.Add( _listeStack );
```

or

```
ListeStacks = new ObservableCollection<UserStackVM>
                                       ( new List<UserStackVM> () { listeStack } );
```